# Animate read more/less JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add an annimation to our read more/less code.
So that is open smooth.

My JQuery code is currently:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.service-info').hide();
      $('.read-more').click(function(){
            $(this).siblings('.service-info').show();
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).parent().find('.read-less').show();
        })
      $('.read-less').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.service-info').hide();
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).parent().find('.read-more').show();
      })
  });
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2bdto5fb/

How can I achieve that?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/2bdto5fb/1/

Comment: just pass int parameter to show and hide function (show(1000) means show the content in 1000 millisecond)

Comment: see the following fiddle if you like http://jsfiddle.net/gDvyR/72/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) and [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) like following.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.service-info').hide();
    $('.read-more').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('.service-info').slideDown('slow');
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).parent().find('.read-less').show();
    })
    $('.read-less').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('.service-info').slideUp('slow');
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).parent().find('.read-more').show();
    })
});
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2bdto5fb/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is to use [slidetoggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) and simplify the code:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.service-info').hide();
  $('.read-more, .read-less').click(function(e){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).parent().find('.read-less, .service-info').slideToggle("slow");
  })
});
```

```css
.read-less {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>

<p class="intro">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis
    natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec,
    pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec,
    vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede
    mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.
    Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis,
    feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam
    ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.</p>

<a href="#" class="read-more">Read more</a>

<div class="service-info">

    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum
        sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies
        nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel,
        aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum
        felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate
        eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante,
        dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum.
        Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.</p>

</div>
<a href="#" class="read-less">Read less</a>
```